# UDP Client sends ping once a second, and also prints anything sent to it?

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, udp

Good afternoon everyone reading this, I am new to programming with sockets, as well as new to asynchronous coding (I feel async may be part of the solution to my problem), so forgive me for any silly mistakes I make.

To start, I have a UDP Echo server that acts as a game server. Anytime it gets a ping sent to it, it adds the source ip and port to a list of "connected clients", and sends that exact ping out to everyone on the list, excluding the sender. This works fairly well, because it reacts upon receiving a message, so it can always just listen. The problem with the client however, is that I need to be constantly sending pings, while also listening.

This is currently what my client looks like:

```
import socket
from time import sleep
from contextlib import contextmanager

UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT_NO = 14004
Message = b"Hello World, From Client B"


@contextmanager
def socket_ctx():
    """ Context Manager for the socket. Makes sure the socket will close regardless of why it exited."""
    my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    # Assign IP address and a RANDOM available port number to socket
    my_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
    try:
        # Let the rest of the app use the socket and wait for it to finish
        yield my_socket
    finally:
        my_socket.close()


def send_data(client_sock):
    client_sock.sendto(Message, (UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NO))


def listen(client_sock):
    print(client_sock.recvfrom(100))



with socket_ctx() as sock:
    while True:
        send_data(sock)
        listen(sock)
        sleep(2)
```

Currently, it sends a ping once, then just idles as it presumably is listening. If it does happen to get a ping back, say, another client send a ping to the server, and the server sent the ping to this client, it hears it, prints it, and starts the loop again. The issue is, without another client sending something to jolt this one out of the listen, it doesn't send it's pings.

I think async might be my solution, but I would have no clue how to go about that. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would implement a server with "receive and handle incoming UDP sockets, plus do some packet-sending once per second" behavior.  Note that this uses the `select()` function to multiplex the two tasks, rather than asynchronous I/O; hopefully that is okay.

```
import socket
import select
import time

UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT_NO = 14004
Message = b"Hello World, From Client B"

udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
print "UDP socket is listening for incoming packets on port", udp_socket.getsockname()[1]

# When we want to send the next periodic-ping-message out
nextPingTime = time.time()

while True:
   secondsUntilNextPing = nextPingTime - time.time();
   if (secondsUntilNextPing < 0):
      secondsUntilNextPing = 0

   # select() won't return until udp_socket has some data
   # ready-for-read, OR until secondsUntilNextPing seconds 
   # have passed, whichever comes first
   inReady, outReady, exReady = select.select([udp_socket], [], [], secondsUntilNextPing)

   if (udp_socket in inReady):
      # There's an incoming UDP packet ready to receive!
      print(udp_socket.recvfrom(100))

   now = time.time()
   if (now >= nextPingTime):
      # Time to send out the next ping!
      print "Sending out scheduled ping at time ", now
      udp_socket.sendto(Message, (UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NO))
      nextPingTime = now + 1.0   # we'll do it again in another second
```

Comment: A couple of questions. Say I wanted to send a lot of pings, like we're talking 20 a second minimum. Would it still be able to efficiently listen for other clients sending that many pings? Thhe second question, is would you mind explaining the `inReady, outReady, exReady = select.select([udp_socket], [], [], secondsUntilNextPing)` bit?

Comment: The number of pings you can send per second will be limited only by your network interface card's outgoing bandwidth--on modern hardware, 20 per second shouldn't cause any problem, regardless of whether you send all 20 at once (e.g. in a for-loop) or do it by reducing the delay-time from 1.0 to (1.0/20.0).  If you get really high-bandwidth (e.g. hundreds of kilobytes per second) you might run into problems with the UDP socket's output-buffer filling up and causing `send()` to block briefly waiting for it to drain, but I wouldn't worry too much about that problem unless/until you bump into it.

Comment: `select()` is a function that will block until there is something to do -- in this case, we're telling it to block until `udp_socket` has some data ready for us to recv(), or until `secondsUntilNextPing` seconds have elapsed, whichever comes first.  It returns a tuple of lists of ready-for-handling sockets; in this case we only care about the `inReady` portion of that tuple, as it will tell us if `udp_socket` has data read-for-read or not.  If `inReady` is empty, OTOH, then `select()` must have returned because it timed out, instead.

Comment: Btw `outReady` and `exReady` are the lists of sockets that are marked as ready-to-be-written-to and have-an-exception-flagged, respectively.  But since we passed in `[]` as the second and third arguments to `select()`, these two return values will always be empty as well, so we can ignore them.  (each of the three return values will always be a subset of its corresponding list that was passed in to `select()`)